# Angular page is not displaying my array items

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to take a response and display the array on the page.  There are no errors, but there also no list on the page.

My list is:  `{"id":4,"content":"Hello, World! "}`

Here is my greeting-list.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { GreetingService } from '../shared/greeting/greeting.service';
import { map } from "rxjs/operators"; 

@Component({
  selector: 'app-greeting-list',
  templateUrl: './greeting-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./greeting-list.component.css']
})
export class GreetingListComponent implements OnInit {
  greetings: Array<any>;

  constructor(private greetingService: GreetingService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    //this.greetingService.getAll().subscribe(data => {
    //  this.greetings = data;
    //});
    this.greetingService.getAll().pipe(map(data => {
      this.greetings = [data];
    }));

  }

}
```

I originally had:

```
    //this.greetingService.getAll().subscribe(data => {
    //  this.greetings = data;
    //});
```

but I was getting an error `Angular: 'Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'` so I changed it to the code below it.

Here is my greeting-list.component.html:

```
<div *ngFor="let greeting of greetings">
  {{greeting.name}}
</div>
```

Comment: `{"id":4,"content":"Hello, World! "}` this is not a list that's why you can not use it in ngFor

Comment: Can you send the exact response from API?

Comment: Assuming you have an array of objects of the form `{id:.., content:..}`, there is no `name` field in it

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava Even if you don't have `name` property it shouldn't give above error. So it looks like the response is not in array form.

Comment: I tried content and id, and both didn't work either.

Comment: @baumli Can you console the data and see if its array or not.

Comment: OP, was there any reason why you originally tagged this question with the [tag:java] tag? I don't see any Java code or mentions of it in your question.

Comment: I'm using spring-boot to generate the list, didn't know if the issue was in my angular or java, but it looks to be in this

Comment: What's do you get with `console.log(data)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to subscribe to the observable:

```
 this.greetingService.getAll().pipe(map(data => {
   this.greetings = [data];
 })).subscribe();
```

Without subscribing the observable will never emit a value.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that, that was exactly what it was.  Once I did that, and changed to `{{greeting.content}}`, then it worked!

Answer (score 0):

*ngFor will only work with arrays (not objects or anything else)

if you are trying too iterate over an object use object.keys(yourbobject)
*ngFor = "let greetingKey of Object.keys(greetings)"

```
<div *ngFor="let greeting of greetings">
  {{greeting[greetingKey].name}}
</div>
```

you will also need to add public object = Object; in your Component TS file